# MySQL Update Conundrum

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called `Advert_images`.  In this table, I may have several records for each `advert_id`.  Each record in the `Advert_images` table has a unique field called "image_id".  e.g.

```
image_id   advert_id   main
---------------------------
1          1           0
2          1           0
3          1           0
4          2           0
5          2           0
```

#### What I want to do is:

Update the field called `main` to 1 **only on the first record (lowest image_id)** for each different `advert_id`.  IE: I would want to update the records with `image_id` of 1 and 4 and set the main field to 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in a single query with MySQL. It doesn't allow you to update a table while also doing a subselect on the table at the same time. However, if it it did, then the query would've been

```
UPDATE Advert_images
SET (main = 1)
WHERE (image_id IN (
   SELECT min(image_id)
   FROM Advert_images
   GROUP BY advert_id
));
```

Nothing says you can't do it in two steps via an external script. Run the inner query to get the ids  of the "lowest" images, then run a separate update query to change the main field values.

Comment: It's possible to do in 1 query.

Answer (score 2):

Using derived tables lets you refer to one table multiple times in `UPDATE` :

```
UPDATE Advert_images a
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT advert_id, MIN(image_id) as image_id FROM Advert_images 
 GROUP BY advert_id)b
ON b.image_id = a.image_id
SET a.main = 1
```

Comment: Wow... had no idea... I would've thought this is not possible, as you're still selecting from the same table you're updating, but I guess in MySQL's guts it's considered two separate queries... big +1.